# One-To-one Database First EF

Tags: sql, entity-framework, one-to-one, ef-database-first

Dear fellow programmers,

I'm stuck on this basic concept within EF and can't find any solution on stackoverflow.

I want to have One-to-One optional relation between: FluxLocation and Address.
(Normal words: a flux location could be provided with a physical address)

Note the database is already present and final.

SQL TABLES:

```
CREATE TABLE sales.sales_flux_location(
id serial PRIMARY KEY,
 -- Many unusefull properties 
sales_address_id integer REFERENCES sales_address
);

CREATE TABLE sales.sales_address(
id serial PRIMARY KEY,
 -- Many unusefull properties 
);
```

EF Mapping:

```
 public partial class FluxLocation
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    //Many unusefull properties.

    [ForeignKey("Address")]
    public int? AddressId { get; set; }
    public Address Address { get; set; }
}

internal partial class FluxLocationConfiguration :    EntityTypeConfiguration<FluxLocation>
{
    public FluxLocationConfiguration()
    {
        //PK
        HasKey(x => x.Id);
        ToTable("sales_flux_location", "sales");
        Property(a => a.Id)
            .HasColumnName("id")
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
        //FK
        HasOptional(l => l.Address)
            .WithOptionalDependent(a => a.FluxLocation);
        Property(l => l.AddressId)
            .HasColumnName("sales_address_id")
            .IsOptional();


   // + mapping other properties.
 }

public partial class Address
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    // other properties

    public FluxLocation FluxLocation { get; set; }
}

internal partial class AddressConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Address>
{
    public AddressConfiguration()
    {
        //PK
        HasKey(a => a.Id);
        ToTable("sales_address", "sales");
        Property(a => a.Id)
            .HasColumnName("id")
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
        //FK
        HasOptional(a => a.FluxLocation).WithOptionalPrincipal(l=>l.Address);

        // mapping many unusefull properties 

}
```

TEST CASE:

```
var dbAddress = Context.AddressSet.Add(new Address {Country = "BEL", CityName="Brussel", Street = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() });
var dbLocation = Context.FluxLocationSet.Add(new FluxLocation { AddressId = dbAddress.Id, Country = "BEL", Type = "MARKET", ExtId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() });
Context.SaveChanges();
```

Error on Context.SaveChanges():

> "42703: column \"Address_Id\" of relation \"sales_flux_location\" does not exist"}

Which is correct because the column name is "sales_address_id".
If any one could help why he is ignoring the propery columnname mapping? 
I'm happy to provide more code if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EF is not picking up that you want sales_address_id as the FK so it tried to create Address_Id. Also, there is some weirdness in how EF does `0:1` - essentially you need to fool it with a `1:M`

So try this:

```
//FK
HasOptional(l => l.Address)
    .WithMany()
    .HasForeignKey(d => d.AddressId);
```

[Link](http://patrickdesjardins.com/blog/how-to-setup-entity-framework-code-first-to-have-only-one-side-0-to-1-relationship)

Comment: of course it is not picking it up, its nowhere configured! The weirdness is not only in 0:1-relationship but also 1:1, since EF will implement each x-to-one relationship as PK=FK per convention. Your proposed solution is only one way to bypass this convention. The other (only other I'm aware of since WithRequired/WithOptional won't let you declare a FK) way is to use Data Annotation ForeignKey. No critic there, just clarification/ addition to this short answer.

Comment: Thanks for the more detailed solution I find a bit tricky to fool EF with this setup. I'm going to still use 1:m as Steve Greene Suggested but map it to a collection and create an other property for EF to ignore that returns the first of item of the list. To have the restriction in code.